# Fail to parse TFRecords while creating TF dataset

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

I'm trying to write a code to parse TFRecords and create TF dataset. I create TFRecords file from a list of images and be able to read it back and decode my image successfully. My code is based on example from this [blog](https://warmspringwinds.github.io/tensorflow/tf-slim/2016/12/21/tfrecords-guide/). But when I try to read my TFRecords file and create TF dataset it fails with this error:

```
ValueError: Argument must be a dense tensor: FixedLenFeature(shape=[], dtype=tf.int64, default_value=None) - got shape [3], but wanted [3, 0]
```

Here is summary of the code which tries to create a dataset:

```
 dataset = tf.data.TFRecordDataset(fnames)
 dataset = dataset.map(parse_tfrec)
```

where `parse_tfrec` is a function to parse single proto record:

```
 def parse_tfrec(example_proto):
    features={
    'height': tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.int64, default_value=IMG_SHAPE[0]),
    'width': tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.int64, default_value=IMG_SHAPE[1]),
    'depth': tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.int64, default_value=IMG_SHAPE[2]),
    'label': tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.int64, default_value=0),
    'image': tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.string, default_value=''),
    }
    parsed_features = tf.parse_single_example(example_proto, features)
    height = tf.cast(features['height'], tf.int32)
    width = tf.cast(features['width'], tf.int32)
    depth = tf.cast(features['depth'], tf.int32)
    label = tf.cast(features['label'], tf.int32)
    image = tf.decode_raw(features['image'], tf.uint8)
    image_shape = tf.pack([height, width, depth])
    image = tf.reshape(image, image_shape)
    return image, label
```

The code fails when it tries to parse the `height` from TFRecords (or any other stored integer). And, I'm not sure I understand the failed message about the shape.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you elaborate on which line the error occurs? Does it occur on the 'parse_single_example' line? Or on the subsequent line?

One thing I noticed is that in your cast statements, you are using the `features` dictionary, instead of `parsed_features`.

Changing your code to be something like this might solve your issue:

```
height = tf.cast(parsed_features['height'], tf.int32)
```

Let me know if the problem persists. I recently had a long day of debugging tfrecords myself :) They can be quite difficult to grasp at first but ultimately I was able to get a huge performance increase in my batch generation time.

Comment: Thanks for spotting this. This is the cause of the error. Unfortunately the example in blog re-use the same variable name and that's why I didn't spot it on my own.

Comment: Great! No problem